# My PC is running slow after changing the driver

Tags: drivers

I have a Dell Inspiron-15-3552 which comes pre-installed with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It has Intel HD 400 Braswell graphics. From the system setting > software and updates> additional drivers I clicked the other one from available options. and applied changes.
After the loading, it was still showing applying changes but I closed the tab. When I restarted my laptop ubuntu detected an internal problem. and it is now running slow and animations are not smooth. Now I can't revert the changes cause those options that are available before are not available now. I am new to Ubuntu. Please help me to fix it. Thanks.

Edit- I don't remember those names exactly cause they are not available under additional drivers anymore. Before this happened. There was 3 options as graphics one was a name with Braswell. This one was selected by default. Other one was Intel. And the third one was do not use this device.
I clicked on the intel one and applied changes.

Edit-2 It's strange that in System settings > Details now my pc is saying 
Graphics- Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe( LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
But it was not this before.

Comment: Strange. The graphics driver for Intel HD 400 is provided as part of the Linux kernel. There should not have been an alternative one, so it is unclear what the "available options" were, and where they came from.   Providing support in this kind of situation is problematic. To clarify the problem, you might want to add more info to the original question, for example, `ubuntu-drivers devices` and `lspci -nnk | grep -A3 VGA`.